# user & group of a file changed after rebooting and login as another user

Tags: reboot

I am using ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox, and I created two accounts with usernames lyg and ygl.

I found a directory VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.18_78361/ in /media, questions got into my mind when I type "ls -l /media/" in my terminal.
Below are two outputs:

1. When I boot and login as lyg,

`-xr-xr-x 4 lyg  lyg    2048 Jun  5 22:33 VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.18_78361`

1. Reboot and login as ygl,

`-xr-xr-x 4 ygl  ygl    2048 Jun  5 22:33 VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.18_78361`

So, why do the user and group change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.18_78361` is automatically mounted by your system upon login from a user using *udev* rules.

What you are seeing is just the system applying those rules. These rules are set by default so that any user can have full permissions to the mounted volumes.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm new to Linux and this is my first post at askubuntu.
your answer is very nice and I'm going to Google "udev" to learn more details.